# Groovy : how to pass closure as parameter to execute the methods inside the class

Tags: groovy, closures

I need to pass a list of methods to execute inside the class with "closure way", see the code bellow

```
 class A{
    def m1(){
      println "Method1"
    }

    def m2(){
      println "Method1"
    }

   def commands = { closure->
      println "before"
      closure.call()
      println "after"    
   }

}


A a = new A()
a.commands{
   println "before execute method m1"
   m1() //A need to execute m1 method of the class A
   println "after execute method m1"
}
```

When I comment the `m1()` the output is

```
  before
  before execute method m1
  after execute method m1
  after
```

otherwise throw the exception `MissingMethodException: No signature of method for method m1()`

So, it does not recognize the `m1()` method as method of `class A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, you may want something like this...

```
class A{
    def m1(){
        println "Method1"
    }

    def m2(){
        println "Method1"
    }

    def commands(closure) {
        def c = closure.clone()
        c.delegate = this
        println "before"
        c()
        println "after"
    }
}
```

The delegate gets an opportunity to respond to method calls that are made inside of the closure.  Setting the delegate to `this` will cause the calls to `m1()` to be dispatched to the instance of `A`.  You may also be interested in setting the `resolveStrategy` property of the closure.  Valid values for `resolveStrategy` are `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`, `Closure.OWNER_FIRST`, `Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY`, `Closure.OWNER_ONLY`. The `owner` is the thing that created the closure and cannot be changed.  The `delegate` can be assigned any object.  When the closure makes method calls the methods may be handled by the `owner` or the `delegate` and the `resolveStrategy` comes into play in deciding which to use.  The names `DELEGATE_ONLY`, `OWNER_ONLY`, `DELEGATE_FIRST` and `OWNER_FIRST` I think are self explanatory.  If you need any more info, let me know.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome ! Great explanation, the solution was simple as expected, don't you love Groovy? I will never back to Java, I don't see any reason to use Java instead of Groovy, I can't understand why Groovy is not so used like python, ruby mainly the fact it is naturally integrated with Java and it compiles for JVM, well, I think when the Java developers knows the Groovy will happen the same that happened with me, never back to Java. Thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Comment: @PlexQ "It also doesn't work well with Java 8." - Everything described above works just fine with Java 8.  The rest of your comment is subjective and not particularly helpful.